# Ubuntu hard drive not detected by BIOS but visible in Disk Management

Tags: boot, hard-drive

I currently have a PC running Windows 10 on an SSD (Legacy BIOS mode) and an extra HDD with games etc. on it. I have installed Ubuntu on ANOTHER separate HDD (1TB) and all went fine (Ubuntu booted up perfectly fine). However, as soon as I reconnected the SATA connection for my SSD with Windows on it and my extra HDD (the one that doesn’t have Ubuntu on it) my BIOS couldn’t detect my third HDD that has Ubuntu on it. The strange part is that Windows Disk management sees the drive and the partitions that Ubuntu created (the swap and main partition).

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have yet to find a fix! And if there is an obvious solution, excuse my ignorance.

Comment: BIOS should not have anything to do with Windows nor Ubuntu. But some have to have drive turned on in BIOS. And that can be by SATA port.

Comment: Your question does not indicate an issue with Ubuntu, your problem may be related to the SATA controller on your motherboard and how it is configured, the model name would help analyzing and finding related reports, but your question is off-topic for this StackExchange site about Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably you are using the BIOS to boot into your Ubuntu installation, but it only works when you don't have the Windows disk atttached.  Probably, your BIOS only looks for the first two disks, the two optical disks, and disks attached through USB as bootable.  See oldFred's comment, for a possibly simple solution.

Here are two other solutions:

1. You could try connecting your Ubuntu disk into "second" position, replacing your Games disk, and putting your Games disk into third position.  This presumes you don't need to boot your Games disk. In any event, you do not want to change the position of your Windows disk.
2. Another approach is to make a "rescue" disk for your Ubuntu installation (grub-mkrescue).  The rescue disk would be on a CD, DVD, or flash drive, all of which would be seen by your BIOS.  You would use your BIOS to boot into the rescue disk, and from there, you would boot into Ubuntu.

The rescue disk would boot into a prompt "grub>".  Once you have that prompt, you would be able to **see all of your disks**.  *And from there, you could then boot your Ubuntu disk.*

The grub> commands you would need include:

- set pager=1  (controls scrolling)
- ls           (lists disks, partitions, files)
- configfile   (used to load grub.cfg in the boot partition in Ubuntu)

Once you have found your Ubuntu disk in grub, you need to find the file /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and type something like (at the "grub>" prompt

configfile (hd2, msdos1)/grub2/grub.cfg
(you will have to explore with "ls" to find the correct parameters).

That is it -- your Ubuntu system should boot from here.

**If you go down this path**, you can refine it later by making a custom "rescue" disk.  You would be adding a simple "grub.cfg" to the rescue disk, which would basically contain the correct "configfile command", so that you could boot your Ubuntu system without typing anything.

**BTW**, I have used this method for a long time, starting with a Windows 98 machine, where I was too afraid to actually modify the Windows disk, and the BIOS on that machine did not recognize the drive on which I had installed RedHat Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
Connect Windows SSD and Ubuntu HDD only. 
Boot using ubuntu HDD making it first boot device. 
Update Grub.
If it goes well, you will get windows 10 entry in grub boot loader.
 Shut down PC and then attach Games Harddisk.

Comment: This does not answer the question. If the question appears to be off-topic then don't answer it with something else like modifying the bootloader setup.